# Hadoop installation on multiple instances of Ubuntu 10.04.1 running on VMware Workstation

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, vmware-workstation, hadoop

I want to learn about Hadoop and run some hands on distributed computing by doing some programming.

I have a PC with Windows 7 Professional installed. On the same PC, I also have a Ubuntu 10.04.1 installed on VMware Workstation 7.

I want to know if the following is possible and how it can be done:

- install multiple Ubuntu virtual machines on same workstation (this
  could be easily done).
- install Hadoop on all these virtual machines and treat the
  architecture as multiple nodes.

Please let me know how to do this (if possible) and how I could test this.

**UPDATE:**

This is resolved. I followed this blog and get it done:

[Running Hadoop on Ubuntu Linux (Single-Node Cluster)](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. How you'd test it is completely dependent on how you are planning on using Hadoop. Regardless of how you're using it, keep in mind that performance in your testing environment is going to be *much* poorer than when the Hadoop nodes are running on their own hardware.

Comment: Hi Eric, but how do I do it???

Comment: I'll give a nutshell version. For more details, consult the documentation for Ubuntu/hadoop/vmware workstation/etc. 1. Install a Ubuntu VM. 2. Install Hadoop on that VM. 3. Clone that VM X times.